# Customize font in Ajax HTML EDITOR EXTENDER.?

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, htmleditorextender

i have to add Tamil fonts in ajax html editor extender. I don't know how to add Tamil font into that. Some one please help me.

my code is:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtContent"/>

<ajax:HtmlEditorExtender id="htmlContent" validatecontrolid="txtContent" enablesanitation="false" runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by Web.Config

```
<globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="ta-IN" uiCulture="de-DE" />
```

And for more information go to this [Link](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/localization/default.aspx)